# Retrieve all users and permissions from an internal Sharepoint website

Tags: item-level-permissions

i have a internal website, and i need to retrieve all users who control the site, and all users that just have read permission.

Is there a way to run a SQL query or any tool that can help . My other option is to enter into each internal section and open permissions to list them, making a copy paste from 34 sections.

Comment: You will need use PowerShell for that, you can find plenty of useful scripts, like this one [User Permissions Audit Report for a Site Collection using PnP PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/09/sharepoint-online-user-permissions-audit-report-using-pnp-powershell.html)